# How to insert custom page in Flutter Pageview.builder?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am using Pageview.builder() widget in my application.

```
PageView.builder(
     itemCount: _newsList.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index){
      if(_newsList.Length != null){
        return Image.network(_newsList[index].image);
     } else Text("No Data");
   }
)
```

Now I want to display a custom image after every 5 pageview image, please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After every 5 images, return the custom image.

```
final customImagesCount = (_newsList.length/5).floor;

var customImagesDisplayedCount = 0;
PageView.builder(
     itemCount: _newsList.length + customImagesCount,
     itemBuilder: (context, index){
      if(index % 5 != 0){
        return Image.network(_newsList[index - customImagesDisplayedCount].image);
      } else {
        customImageDisplayCount++;
        // return your CustomImage
      }
   }
)
```

Comment: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..9: 10

Comment: Updated the solution. It was due to the accessing _newsList array.